zooming on an image in latex beamer for frame transitions
I was looking into how effectively zoom-in an image in LaTex beamer and I was dissatisfied by the results I achieved, so I'm here asking for some suggestions.
Basically, I have a three step workflow (see image) which I placed in a frame and where I might (or might not) add a short description of the three phases on the left with column; however, the main point is that I wish to create some zooming effect in the next three slides where each one of them zoom-in one of the three (CONSTRUCTION, MAPPING or DOWNSTREAM ANALYSES) aspects of the workflow.
The experiment I've done with \framezoom didn't work that well... I hoped to have the exact portion of the workflow cropped out and enlarged in the following slide(s), centered in the middle, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.
This is the code I'm using, let me know. Thanks in advance!
\documentclass[169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{bground}{HTML}{005EB8}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
        {\begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \fill [color=bground] (0,0.868\paperheight) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=anti-flashwhite}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-.1in}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bringing together the graph and population \\ genetics: the workflow}
    
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth,height=.75\textheight]{example-image}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



"The experiment I've done with \framezoom didn't work that well." isn't a particular useful problem description. Show what you tried and describe why the result does not satisfy your needs.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz apologies, I was mostly zooming into one area generating overlapping between the original image and the zoomed section.

As you are anyway using tikz, you could use it to clip different parts of your image:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}   
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bringing together the graph and population \\ genetics: the workflow}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth,max height=.75\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip<2> (-6,3)  rectangle (6,7);
\clip<3> (-6,-2)   rectangle (6,2);
\clip<4> (-6,-3) rectangle (6,-7);
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1.5\textheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



that's fantastic! I played a bit with the numbers to get the exact coordinates for the three parts, the result is very clean. I was wondering, this is not necessary and beyond point maybe, but once presenting is there a way to implement the zooming effect from the original workflow to just even the first part (if not possible for all of them) in slideshow mode? Say give the idea that a part from the original image is enlarging like the \framezoom effect, but this could lead to quality loss I suspect?
